# Changed SolidColorBrush in TextBox Style

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles, brush

I already tried to ask, but probably I did not provide enough information. I am trying to create my own WPF Theme. Everything was ok until I created this style.

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Grid>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="PART_ContentHost">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0.5"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Background">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red"/>
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Stroke).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Background">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Yellow"/>
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="ReadOnly"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="Background" Fill="{StaticResource OniiControlBackgroundBrush}" Stroke="{StaticResource OniiNormalBrush}" RadiusX="2" RadiusY="2"/>
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
</Style>
```

It's supposed to change color of TextBox Background and BorderBrush when TextBox is Disabled.

Colors are defined in same ResourceDictionary

```
<Color x:Key="MainColor">#FF595959</Color>
<Color x:Key="OniiControlBackgroundColor">#FF333333</Color>

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="OniiNormalBrush" Color="{StaticResource MainColor}"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="OniiControlBackgroundBrush" Color="{StaticResource OniiControlBackgroundColor}" />
```

And what is really my problem I don't know. What I know:

*1/ "When TextBox is disabled, it changes the color of everything what uses OniiControlBackgroundBrush To Red Color"*

- OniiControlBackgroundBrush is referenced in other styles as StaticResource

*2/ "When I switch those colors still only OniiControlBackgroundBrush is changed but this time to Yellow"*

```
<Rectangle x:Name="Background" Fill="{StaticResource OniiNormalBrush}" Stroke="{StaticResource OniiControlBackgroundBrush}" RadiusX="2" RadiusY="2"/>
```

- OniiNormalBrush is also referenced in other styles as StaticResource

*3/ "Everything is defined in one resource dictionary"*

```
    <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Theme/OniiResourceDictionary.xaml">
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

*4/ "I tried reproduce this problem in smaller solution with less custom styles and I did not succeeded"*

- I used same TextBox style.

  ```
  <TextBox Height="32" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="38,51,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="215" />
  <CheckBox Content="Enabled" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="259,51,0,0" Name="checkBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Checked="checkBox1_Checked" Unchecked="checkBox1_Unchecked" />
  <Border Height="148" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="254,126,0,0" Name="border1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="98" />
  <Rectangle Fill="{StaticResource OniiNormalBrush}" StrokeThickness="20" Stroke="{StaticResource OniiControlBackgroundBrush}" Height="148" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="358,126,0,0" Name="rectangle5" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="99" />
  ```
- Textbox is Disabled and Enabled by CheckBox, Border Uses custom style with both colors as StaticResources

*5/ "When I add following code to my original solution problem disappears"*

```
<Rectangle Height="71" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="130,131,0,0" Name="rectangle2" StrokeThickness="20" Stroke="{StaticResource OniiControlBackgroundBrush}" Fill="{StaticResource OniiNormalBrush}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="98" />
```

Am I really missing something? Or Am I just really stupid? Anyway Your help would be appreciated. I am really lost. Well and last thing I don't want to use x:Shared="false" mainly because I see there is no problem with changing OniiNormalBrush. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to lie in your resource bindings.  When you use a StaticResource it means that the resource is loaded when the window initializes and then it is never loaded again.  Thus, in most cases, when you modify the resource the controls that are bound to it are unaware of the change.

In #4 you didn't experience the problem because you used DynamicResource, which allows the resource to be updated at runtime.

Edit:  In looking over things a second time it looks like it could be one of two things.

One.. the static binding of the color doesn't allow for updating.  Does making the change from Static to Dynamic when binding your Color to your Brush fix the issue?

```
<Color x:Key="MainColor">#FF595959</Color>
<Color x:Key="OniiControlBackgroundColor">#FF333333</Color>

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="OniiNormalBrush" Color="{DynamicResource MainColor}"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="OniiControlBackgroundBrush" Color="{DynamicResource OniiControlBackgroundColor}" />
```

Two... The animation is setting the color on the brush.. which is essentially clearing out the binding by having a direct color assigned to it.  I would have assumed that when the animation ended that the color would be set back to the binding, but this may not be the case.  Does this have any effect:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="OniiNormalBrush" Color="#FF595959"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="OniiControlBackgroundBrush" Color="#FF333333" />
```

Comment: There is no problem changing color of textbox... color of brush OniiControlBackgroundBrush changes everywhere. I don't want that. In #4 when I reference Brush as StaticResource it doesn't seem to have problem as well.

Comment: Right, but in the upper examples you're statically binding the brush's color.  Color="{StaticResource MainColor}".  I presume that in your lower examples you're not doing this. Resources give you a reference to the object. In the case of colors, if you put in a new color then the reference changes and anything that's referenced statically will not get the update, but dynamicResource references would see the new color.  Also, the default value for x:Shared is true, so manually setting it to true doesn't have any additional effect.

Comment: Yes, that is the problem. i have both brushes referenced everywhere as StaticResource. So I don't expect them to change. The worst problem is that one of those brushes gets updated where it's supposed to and second gets updated EVERYWHERE it's used. I am sorry with that x:Shared="true" a messed up. What I ment was x:Shared="false" And I also edited #4 where I used StaticResource this time. Still same result. One color gets updated everywhere and second does  only where it's supposed to.